# VM / Dev problems for Mac/Windows development with PHP/MySQL/GIT

Tags: php, git, centos, virtualbox

I currently have a problem with how to setup my virtual environment for my LAMP stack. The site I'm developing is a web application written in PHP and uses MySQL for the database. Right now, I have a single VM running inside Virtualbox with CentOS. I run the web/mysql server in it and have my code folder setup with GIT.

The host OS (Mac/Windows) currently is setup with a SAMBA share to access the code inside the GIT folder on the VM. From this, I use SourceTree and PHPStorm to manipulate the files and make commits. Permissions on the files/folders are set with a force mask (which doesn't seem to be possible with NFS)

(Samba server on CentOS(guest os), Samba client on Windows/Mac(host os))

The problems occur on occasion when I run my environment like this. I've had my GIT repository have weird errors and corrupting (HEAD detaching, index files corrupting / being too small, other .git files corrupting). There is also an issue where the file names are case insensitive and the CentOS guest OS runs it as case sensitive.

---

**Ultimately, my questions is:** How can I setup my development environment to execute the code inside my CentOS Guest OS, have file permissions not be a hassle when I'm commiting/executing, allow me to setup an environment that will match my multi-server environment (ie. multiple Virtualbox instances), and have it run into no or minor problems as if I was just running it all under CentOS for development?

I would prefer to be able to run VirtualBox, be able to develop my software using my PHPStorm/SourceTree applications on my Host OS, and avoid any problems that lead to corruption of my filesystem in GIT.

Comment: Are you running the VM locally? If so, why are you running it through a VM? I develop all my sites locally on a windows enviroment and have never run into an issue.

Comment: Samba server on CentOS, Samba client on Windows/Mac.

Comment: VM is running locally. It is running through a VM because it is suppose to match the production environment so we don't run into issues, and it has quite a bit of software to setup. There are things that create problems configuring in windows/mac with MAMP/WAMP such as php extensions and software other than MySQL, like HAProxy/NGINX/iptables.